# How to set text editable in GtkEntry

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome, gtk2

Pretty straight forward question, I have a `GtkEntry` widget that I want to set to be editable.  I know the function I should use is:

```
gtk_editable_set_editable
```

But I don't know how to make it take a `GtkEntry` widget as an argument

Here is the code I'm using:

```
GtkWidget *TextEntry;
TextEntry = gtk_entry_new();

gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(TextEntry), TRUE);
gtk_entry_set_editable(GTK_ENTRY(TextEntry), TRUE);
gtk_entry_set_overwrite_mode(GTK_ENTRY(TextEntry), TRUE);
gtk_widget_set_can_focus(GTK_WIDGET(TextEntry), TRUE);
gtk_widget_grab_focus(TextEntry);

panel_applet_request_focus(applet, 10);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (applet), TextEntry);

gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (applet));
```

So far as getting keyboard focus, I think I need the `panel_applet_request_focus ()` function.  It requires that i pass it the applet in question and the timestamp of the event triggering the window focus

I'm not sure what to put in for the timestamp.  I compiled the code as above and I still can't get keyboard focus when I click the applet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

```
GtkWidget* entry = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_entry_set_editable(GTK_ENTRY(entry), TRUE);
```

Welcome to the world of GObject :)

Note that if you were using gtk_editable, you need to do:

```
gtk_editable_set_editable(GTK_EDITABLE(entry), TRUE);
```

Comment: @SB: Tried that, resulting in the following error:
 error: cannot convert ‘GtkEntry*’ to ‘GtkEditable*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void gtk_editable_set_editable(GtkEditable*, gboolean)’

Comment: That's odd.  The docs indicate that GtkEntry implements GtkEditable.  Did you try the deprecated gtk_entry_set_editable to see what happens?

Comment: this is daft, but what do you mean by depreciated?

Comment: Deprecated means the API shouldn't be used anymore in favor of another.  http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-editable  is what I'm talking about.  Try the first suggestion I have in my answer using gtk_entry_set_editable as opposed to gtk_editable_set_editable.

Comment: Ok i used the depreciated one and it compiled fine.  It would appear to be something else.  Basically when i click on the text Box i want to be able to type in characters and such, but its not picking it up.  Thank for you help SB.

Comment: GtkEntry and setting it editable is exactly what you want.   You'll need to post code so I can see your issue.

Comment: You may want to look at gtk_widget_get_events () and gtk_widget_add_events () to make sure the events mask is correct.  http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-events

Also can you post the code that didn't work with gtk_editable_set_editable?

Comment: @paultop6: That's "deprecated", there's no 'i' in there.